# Publish REST service with Java SE

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to find a simple way to publish my RESTful web service using JAX-RS 2.0 with Java SE using Jersey and/or the Java SE build-in http server.

I want to keep my dependencies to the minimum so i wanted to avoid grizzly and also do not want to use any external application server.

Can you point me how to publish a rest service with this requirements?

Thanks in advance,

I mean to achieve somethig like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://localhost:8080/calculator/",new ResourceConfig(SumEndpoint.class));

        System.in.read();
        server.stop();

} catch (IOException ex) {
}
```

}

... but avoiding the grizzly dependency

Comment: You haven't asked a question (and requests to recommend tools are generally off-topic here but might be on-topic at Server Fault).

Comment: I've used [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/) as an experiment. It seems to work nicely.

Comment: chrylis i think question is clear ... however i've edited to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just depend on

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

you can then start the server

```
JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:8090/root"),
        new MyApplication());
```

where MyApplication extends ResourceConfig to obtain resource scanning.

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("...");
    }
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public Response foo() {

        return Response.ok("Hey, it's working!\n").build();
    }
}
```

There may a better way to control the server life cycle, but that eludes me for the moment.

Comment: Looks simply enough, thank you ... can you,please, refer to me how to correctly extend ResourceConfig or write down a very simple example? ... i am getting some strange problems java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newIdentityHashSet()Ljava/util/Set;

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
 <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
 <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @Rafael I just extended ResourceConfig instead of Application and included the packages where my resource classes resides.

Comment: hi. Have you seen that work with no-empty ApplicationPath?

Comment: What would be the URL to get the foo() response? I tried your example and the server is running, but I keep getting 404 not found. I tried: http://localhost:8090/root/ and also root/foo/, among others...